# The IMAP server replied to the 'SEARCH' command with a 'BAD' response

Tags: imap, mailkit

I'm trying to fetch specific number of emails from Gmail using MailKit.net library.but there is an error while executing the search command:

> The IMAP server replied to the 'SEARCH' command with a 'BAD' response

here is my code:

```
        var startRange = (page - 1) * pageSize;
        var endRage = page * pageSize;

        var range = new UniqueIdRange(new UniqueId((uint)startRange), 
        new UniqueId((uint)endRage));

        var uIds = Client.Inbox.Search(range, SearchQuery.All).Reverse();
```

and here is imap.log file content:

```
Connected to imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/
S: * OK Gimap ready for requests from 151.240.143.192 a1mb311709115lfh
C: A00000000 CAPABILITY
S: * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN AUTH=OAUTHBEARER AUTH=XOAUTH
S: A00000000 OK Thats all she wrote! a1mb311709115lfh
C: A00000001 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN AHNhZS5oZW1tYXRpQGdtYWlsLmNvbSAAMDg2ODQxMTkxOTA4NjMx
S: * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LITERAL- SPECIAL-USE APPENDLIMIT=35651584
S: A00000001 OK sae.hemmati@gmail.com authenticated (Success)
C: A00000002 NAMESPACE
S: * NAMESPACE (("" "/")) NIL NIL
S: A00000002 OK Success
C: A00000003 LIST "" "INBOX"
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "INBOX"
S: A00000003 OK Success
C: A00000004 LIST (SPECIAL-USE) "" "*"
S: * LIST (\All \HasNoChildren) "/" "[Gmail]/All Mail"
S: * LIST (\Drafts \HasNoChildren) "/" "[Gmail]/Drafts"
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren \Sent) "/" "[Gmail]/Sent Mail"
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren \Junk) "/" "[Gmail]/Spam"
S: * LIST (\Flagged \HasNoChildren) "/" "[Gmail]/Starred"
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren \Trash) "/" "[Gmail]/Trash"
S: A00000004 OK Success
C: A00000005 LIST "" "[Gmail]"
S: * LIST (\HasChildren \Noselect) "/" "[Gmail]"
S: A00000005 OK Success
C: A00000006 EXAMINE INBOX (CONDSTORE)
S: * FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $NotPhishing $Phishing)
S: * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ()] Flags permitted.
S: * OK [UIDVALIDITY 611076938] UIDs valid.
S: * 16612 EXISTS

S: * 0 RECENT
S: * OK [UIDNEXT 16834] Predicted next UID.
S: * OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 1442114]
S: A00000006 OK [READ-ONLY] INBOX selected. (Success)
C: A00000007 UID SEARCH RETURN () UID 0:10
S: A00000007 BAD Could not parse command
```

Any clues?
thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it's because it doesn't like 0 as a UID.  Try starting at 1.

Comment: I would agree with @Max. For most API's, I've added checks that the UIDs are within the valid range (i.e. not `0`), but apparently I didn't do that for the `UniqueIdRange` .ctor.

Comment: I've updated `UniqueId` and `UniqueIdRange` .ctors to not allow invalid UIDs and/or ranges. They will now throw `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast reply! you're right! the problem is about UId. but it's odd that on some other mail servers the starting uId is 0.

Comment: No IMAP server starts with a UID of 0. Most likely you just got lucky in that they ignored it.

Comment: Might be more than luck... some servers accept moderately invalid input for `SEARCH`, such as out-of-range UIDs and MSNs and flag names that the RFC allows but this implementation not.